# MVVM TextBlock doesn't update text on runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

[image]I'm trying to understand the mvvm model. So I followed along this youtube tutorial: 
[YoutubeVideo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LKiYpmHxhc)

I have a class called Person. In the first textbox of the view you can insert your name and in the second the lastname. The Textblock should automatically update with the fullname property but **this happens only on design time** and I don't have any clue why.

Here is the xaml of the Mainpage:

```
<Page
x:Class="PropertyChanged.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:PropertyChanged"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:m="using:PropertyChanged.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Page.Resources>
    <m:Person x:Key="person"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource person}}" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Lastname, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Fullname}" Width="Auto"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And my Person class in the namespace PropertyChanged.Models:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    private string lastname;

    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return lastname; }
        set { lastname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Lastname");
            OnPropertyChanged("FullName");
        }
    }

    private string fullname;

    public string Fullname
    {
        get { return name +" " +lastname; }
        set { fullname = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Fullname");
        }
    }

    public Person()
    {
        if (DesignMode.DesignModeEnabled)
        {
            this.Name = "Matthias";
            this.Lastname = "Herrmann";
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Typo: `OnPropertyChanged("FullName");` and the property is called `Fullname` with a lower case "n".

Comment: Note that this is a good place (and reason) to use the `nameof` operator instead of the actual string.

Comment: Oh ok thanks thought this is maybe a logical mistake from me

Comment: FYI, `<Page.DataContext><m:Person /></Page.DataContext>`

Comment: @BradleyDotNET how would I use nameof in this context? nameof(fullname) ?

Comment: @MatthiasHerrmann Right `nameof(Fullname)` That wouldn't compile if you had the field name wrong (as you do here)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Ok thanks

Comment: This can also be avoided with [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://grenangen.se/node/75), although I personally prefer to specify the property expliclty with a [type-safe implementation](http://byteflux.me/creating-a-type-safe-implementation-of-the-inotifypropertychanged-interface/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to take back my previous response.
I tested the code on my system and it works, it could change the names and the `TextBlock` was updated at runtime.

The only thing I have different is the code to detect whether design time is active:

```
        if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
        {
            this.Name = "Matthias";
            this.Lastname = "Herrmann";
        }
```

However I still would not recommend to use a `StaticResource` for an object that will be edited during runtime.

You can change the properties of the object during runtime and will able to see the changes in the UI because of the change notification in the properties, but you could not re-set the `Person` object itself because of the nature of a `StaticResource`, this might be confusing.

Comment: Not sure that's correct, the data context is set to a static resource but does that stop properties of the object from still notifying?

Comment: @kidshaw I agree with you

Comment: Credit to you for updating your response, I'd still add though - static resources are preferable unless you need to change the instance, how often have you needed to do that? I don't mean setting the data context to a new object, I mean reinitialing the bound object itself. Just getting my head around how you'd do that and I'm sure if you get there, your design ain't right. Using static is more memory efficient to boot.

Comment: I usually work in scenarios where data is loaded at runtime, and in this case the data is loaded after the view is finished initializing itself, in the loaded event of the view (i.e. not in the constructor of the view or in the construtor view model). I believe i would not be able to use the approach with the static resource in this case. But in the example here it is ok to do so. For instance of you have a Data Access Layer which returns a `Person` object, you would like to set the whole object in your view model and not each individual property of it.